# Get documents names list when document include nested document in Firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

'chatrooms' collection is include documents for example document name is `'PNJAHph61ZStU7IANgBfXAwW66l2-e8GhTlpLyWSdmmBuMlyrfgiJYlI3'`

`'PNJAHph61ZStU7IANgBfXAwW66l2-e8GhTlpLyWSdmmBuMlyrfgiJYlI3'` document include 'messeges' document and 'messeges' document include sub document

I need to get the document name list include in the 'chatrooms' collection.
In a normal case, this function works like that but in nested case, it does not work

```
firebase.firestore().collection("chatrooms")
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(doc.data()); // For data inside doc
                console.log(doc.id); // For doc id
            }
        )});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "document include nested document"?

Comment: Are you trying to list IDs of documents in messages sub-collection?

Comment: I'm trying to get the sub-document IDs list under the chatrooms collection

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a symbiotic link through data aggregation, as paths in the collection and sub-collections are not linked beyond the name path reference. Additionally, you cannot simply fetch all document names in a collection without reading all the document's `data()` which would incur reads with billing

so if you need a list of all names, you must create an `array` of all sub-collection names in the parent document or in a dedicated document called `_index`